# conditional match in nested structure in all documents - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a structure like this -

```
[
  {
    "name": "person1",
    "age": "16",
    "marks": 91
  },
  {
    "name": "person2",
    "age": "18",
    "qualification": [
      {
        "masters": [
          {
            "semester": {
              "number": "1",
              "subject": {
                "computer": 56,
                "english": 34,
                "hindi": 92
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "semester": {
              "number": "2",
              "subject": {
                "computer": 54,
                "english": 31
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "bachelors": [
          {
            "semester": {
              "number": "1",
              "subject": {
                "computer": 54,
                "english": 81
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "semester": {
              "number": "2",
              "subject": {
                "computer": 67,
                "english": 42
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "person3",
    "age": "19",
    "qualification": [
      {
        "masters": [
          {
            "semester": {
              "number": "1",
              "subject": {
                "computer": 94,
                "english": 100
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "semester": {
              "number": "2",
              "subject": {
                "computer": 45,
                "english": 21
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "bachelors": [
          {
            "semester": {
              "number": "1",
              "subject": {
                "computer": 34,
                "english": 63
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "semester": {
              "number": "2",
              "subject": {
                "computer": 60,
                "english": 80
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to project all names who have once scored 90 or more marks. But condition is little complex than just fetching 90. For someone whose age is less than 18, we need to check `marks` field, for someone whose age is more than or equal to 18, we need to look at all `computer` and `english` (not hindi) fields. So, in our case it should report person1 and person3. This query is going to run on around a 100k records, should be performant as well. I have tried various combinations of $cond, $match. But haven't been able to scratch a proper aggregate query -

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "marks": {
        $gte: 90,
        $lte: 100
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "name": 1
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/l4zD05iKjyp

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tEiK7FfOFLR

Comment: Works, do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following aggregate pipeline achieves the desired output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {
      $or: [
        { 
          "age": { $lt: 18 },
          "marks": { $gte: 90 }
        },
        {
          "age": { $gte: 18 },
          $or: [
            { "qualification.masters.semester.subject.computer": {
                $gte: 90
            } },
            { "qualification.masters.semester.subject.english": {
                $gte: 90
            } },
            { "qualification.bachelors.semester.subject.computer": {
                $gte: 90
            } },
            { "qualification.bachelors.semester.subject.english": {
                $gte: 90
            } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $project: {
      "name": 1,
      "_id": 0
  } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tEiK7FfOFLR)

In the above pipeline, the initial [`$match`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage looks for documents that satisfy the given conditions:

- For people with age less than 18, directly check the `marks` field.
- For people with age 18 or more, check the scores in `computer` and `english` subjects for both `masters` and `bachelors`.

After filtering the documents based on the conditions, project only the `name` field in the next stage.

This aggregation should return the desired result and would be performant on a collection of size around 100k. However, if performance becomes an issue, ensure you have the appropriate indexes created on the collection, such as on `age`, `marks`, and the `qualification` array fields.